# Python 2.7 regex statement with multiple option acute and grave accents

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a python regex statement that will work with 2 optional characters.  Below is the basic regex statement I'm working off of.

```
word = re.sub(ur'ö:wä', ur'ö:wë', word)  #change the a to e

word = re.sub(ur'ö́:wä̀', ur'ö́:wë̀', word)  # both acute accents

word = re.sub(ur'ö̀:wä́', ur'ö̀:wë́', word)  # ö has grave accent and ä has acute
...
```

The problem I'm having is that both `ö` and `ä` can have both, either and/or neither the acute accent or grave accent so any variation of the following,`ö́`, `ä́`, `ö̀`, `ä̀`.  If an accent is present on the `ä`, I'd like the `ë` to have the corresponding accent.  I having a hard time trying to figure out how to do this regex statement without having all the variations of the single statement above.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to search disregarding accents, how about using a transliteration tool like `unidecode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

def change(word):
    return re.sub(ur'(ö[̀́]?:w)ä([̀́]?)', ur'\1ë\2', word)

for word in [u'nö:wäy', u'nö́:wä̀y', u'nö̀:wä́y']:
    print word, "->", change(word)
```

prints:

```
nö:wäy -> nö:wëy
nö́:wä̀y -> nö́:wë̀y
nö̀:wä́y -> nö̀:wë́y
```

which should look like this:

- nö:wäy -> nö:wëy
- nö́:wä̀y -> nö́:wë̀y
- nö̀:wä́y -> nö̀:wë́y

Unless I have misunderstood what you want to do, you're looking for function `change`.

This works because grave and acute accents on an already accented letter are represented as second unicode characters, combining the already accented letter with one more accent.  In general, this approach will work for "decomposed" unicode characters: it will work for "ó:wà" and "ò:wá" (where "à" is represented as `u'a\u0300'` but it will not work for "ó:wà" or "ò:wá" (where "à" is represented as `u'\u00e0'`).  If you want it to work for all cases, you need a dictionary such as the one that @AlexMartelli suggested.  In that case, I would suggest to include in the dictionary all representations of accented characters, precomposed and decomposed.

For further information, read about [unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

Comment: thanks for the help!  so the accents are within the brackets?  sorry it's kind of hard to tell.

Comment: Yes, they are inside the brackets.  The brackets stand for "optionally, a grave or an acute accent".

Answer (score 1):

What about...:

```
a2e = {u'ä':u'ë̀', u'ä̀':u'ë́', u'ä́':u'ë'}  # or whatever
def match_accents(mo):
    s = mo.group(0)
    return s[:-1] + a2e[s[-1]]

word = re.sub(ur'[öö́ö̀]:w[ää̀ä́]', match_accents, word)  # change the a to e
```

The key idea is that you can pass a **function** as `sub`'s second argument: that function is then called with the match-object for each match and must return the string with which that match needs to be replaced.  In this case I'm using a simple `dict` to determine the replacement (though I think I got the correspondences wrong, as I can barely spot the differences, I'm sure it will be very easy for you to fix:-).